# How to re-render a template using a cached property in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a route that finds a day object using day of week

```
//assume I have a configuration model for 7 days (1 for each week day basically)
var day_of_week = ev.date.getDay() + 1;
var model = App.Day.find(day_of_week);
model.set('date', selected_date); //selected_date is mm/dd/yyyy (input from user)
router.transitionTo('day', model);
```

In that route I redirect to another that knows about a related object

```
App.DayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('appointments');
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return {day_date: model.get('date')};
    }
});
```

In that template I each over the objects

```
{{#each appointment in controller}}
  {{appointment}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

This is a basic computed property

```
appointments: function() {
  //do stuff in here
}.property()
```

What I've noticed is that when I first load the day my computed property (at the very bottom of the stack shown above) is invoked like it should be. But when I come back to that day I can't get the computed property to fire (assuming because it's a model already loaded / cached in memory).

I need to reload this because I do change the date (even if the rest of the object is exactly the same).

How can I force this re-render / aka- stop the cached property when the date changes? I've tried to modify the property to trigger when date changes but still no dice ...

```
appointments: function() {
  //do stuff in here
}.property('date')
```

**Update -showing the full model w/ the computed property**

My appointments computed property (shown above) actually hangs off my model (because it's configuration based on the day model)

```
App.Day = DS.Model.extend({
    times: [],
    first: attr('string'),
    last: attr('string'),
    interval: attr('number'),
    day_of_week: attr('number'),
    date: attr('string'),
    listings: function() {
        return App.Appointment.find(this);
    }.property(),
    slots: function() {
        var slots = App.Slot.find(); //this returns configuration -not persisted data from $.ajax)
        for(var i = 0; i < slots.get('length'); i++) {
            if (slots.objectAt(i).get('day_of_week') === this.get('day_of_week')) {
                var slot = slots.objectAt(i);
                slot.set('day', this);
                this.get('times').push(slot);
            }
        }
        return this.get('times');
    }.property(),
    appointments: function() {
        App.Appointment.clear(); //just resets this js array each time to get a fresh apt collection (again -because it's dynamic based on configuration)
        var slots = this.get('slots');
        var interval = this.get('interval');
        for(var i = 0; i < slots.get('length'); i++) {
            var entry = App.AppointmentFactory.create(slots.objectAt(i), interval);
            App.Appointment.add(entry);
        }
        return this.get('listings');
    }.property()
});
```

**Update Again**

Looks like I forgot to show the Appointments index route -very important as it shows how I populate the appointments array for the given day model

```
App.AppointmentsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var day = this.modelFor("day");
        return day.get('appointments');
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the computed property? In the controller?

Comment: I added the full model above (computed property lives on the model in this case). I also added the appointments route to show how its wired up

Comment: What about making the `slots()` computed property dependent on `.property('date')` and `appointments()` computed property dependent on `.property('slots')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include `@each` for that, if infact `date` appears on every occurrence of appointment, and your computedProperty is at the `appointments` level.

alternatively, you can prevent caching using `.volatile()`, but this shouldn't be needed with correctly defined observers.

Comment: it looks like volatile was the missing link -I thought this was depreciated or talked about being depreciated a while back?

Comment: The final solution for anyone following -I added volatile to listings/slots/appointments

Answer (score 1):

The way to find the answer is to see the code inside `appointments` to find which properties you are using that change and that should be used to recompute the `appointments` property